# How to find the last element in an object where the value === true

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

If this is important, I am working in a react mob-x store. I have an object that I am converting to an array and looping through and doing various things. I need to find the last instance of the object where the value === true to then have the key to use in a comparison. (ex. if(panelName === panel (of the last instance where the value is true).

I am having trouble finding the last item where value === true. I tried using arr.length -1 but that of course just finds the last one regardless of what the value is. The object key and length are both variable, the value is either 'true or false'. Thank you.

```
panelsSaved = {EE: true, SS: false, RR: false, FF: true, WW: false}

@action expandNextPanel(panelName){
        const panelsSaved = this.filterValuesData.panelsSaved;
        const panels = Object.entries(panelsSaved);

        for (const [panel, value] of panels){
            if(value === true && panel !== panelName){
                //do stuff
                break;
            }
        }
```

I am upvoting most of the answers because it sort of took a combination of a few of them to get this working.

````
        let panelsUsed = {EE: true, SS: false, RR: false, FF: true, WW: false};
      
        if(panelsUsed.length !== 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i <= panelsUsed.length; i++) {
                if(panelsUsed[i] !== panelName){
                    if(panelsUsed[i] !== undefined) {
                      'do stuff'
                       break;
                    } else {
                       'do other stuff'
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        let panelsFiltered = panelsUsed.filter((panel) => {return panel !== panelName});
        this.filterValuesData.panelsUsed = panelsFiltered;
   
    
    } ```
Thank you everyone for your input!
````

Comment: Objects are not ordered collections, so there is not "last" one.

Answer (score 1):

simply :

```js
const panelsSaved = { EE: true, SS: false, RR: false, FF: true, WW: false }

const LastTrue = obj => Object.entries(obj)
                              .filter(([k,v])=>v)
                              .reverse()[0][0]

console.log( LastTrue(panelsSaved) )
```

OR, with a Loop

```js
const panelsSaved = { EE: true, SS: false, RR: false, FF: true, WW: false }


function LastTrue(obj)
  {
  let rep;
  for (let key in obj) if (obj[key]) rep=key
  return rep
  }
  
console.log( LastTrue(panelsSaved))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's quite many ways to approach this, but here's a couple of ways.

You could iterate the array in reverse order and return the first one that matches `true`:

```
function lastWhere(arr, fn) {
  if (arr.length === 0) return undefined;

  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const candidate = arr[i];
    if (fn(candidate)) {
      return candidate;
    }
  }

  return undefined;
}

// ...

const panelsSaved = this.filterValuesData.panelsSaved;
const panels = Object.entries(panelsSaved);

const [panel, value] = lastWhere(panels, ([panel, value]) => value === true)
```

Or perhaps you could use `.map()` to map the values to `true` or `false` and use `.lastIndexOf()` to find the last one that's `true`:

```
function lastWhereTrue(arr, fn) {
  const mapped = arr.map((candidate) => fn(candidate));
  const matchingIndex = arr.lastIndexOf(true);
  return mapped[matchingIndex];
}

// ...

const panelsSaved = this.filterValuesData.panelsSaved;
const panels = Object.entries(panelsSaved);

const [panel, value] = lastWhere(panels, ([panel, value]) => value === true)
```

Then, if you need to go through the entire list of panels and do something to all of them and specifically do something to the last panel, you could just compare either the `panel` or the `value`, depending on which one is unique.

```
const panelsSaved = this.filterValuesData.panelsSaved;
const panels = Object.entries(panelsSaved);

const last = lastWhere(panels, ([panel, value]) => value === true)

for (const [panel, value] of panels) {
  if (panel === last.panel) {
    // ...
  }
  // or
  if (value === last.value) {
      // ...
  }
}
```

---

Example of the solution which I suggested in the comments:

```
const panelsSaved = this.filterValuesData.panelsSaved;
const panels = Object.entries(panelsSaved);

let lastTruePanel = null;
for (const [panel, value] of panels.reverse()) {
    if (value === true && !lastTrueValueProcessed) {
        // This is the entry which is the last value===true
        lastTrueValueProcessed = [panel, value];
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, great...thank you! I meant to add I tried to reverse it but that didn't seem to work because of the order of things that needed to be done in my, 'do stuff' ha. 

I will try your mapping solution!

Comment: @Ash I've updated my solution to clarify that you'll need to find the "last" one beforehand if you're iterating the list from the start. If the order doesn't matter in the `for` loop, you could just do `for (const [panel, value] of [...panels].reverse()) { }` and have a boolean value outside the loop that keeps track of whether you've already processed a panel with `value === true` and only do the additional processing if it's true. And of course set it to false after the additional processing.

Comment: I like the last example you provided but what is unique is the panel but I won't know what panel is until I find out the last instance where value === true. So looks like maybe mapping will be a good place to start. Thank you.

Comment: @Ash I added an example of what I just suggested.

Comment: in your last suggestion, how do I compare the panel of the last instance where value is true to panelName (my variable passed in initially)? Thank yoU!

Comment: @Ash I've updated my answer. You can access `lastTruePanel[0]` and `lastTruePanel[1]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227065/discussion-between-ash-and-cbr).

Answer (score 1):

Just use classical `for` loop in reverse order (`for...of` loop cannot be used in such way).

```js
panelsSaved = {EE: true, SS: false, RR: false, FF: true, WW: false}

@action expandNextPanel(panelName){
        const panelsSaved = this.filterValuesData.panelsSaved;
        const panels = Object.entries(panelsSaved);

        for (var i = panels.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            const [panel, value] = panels[i]
            if(value === true && panel !== panelName){
                // do stuff
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let panelsSaved = { EE: true, SS: false, RR: false, FF: true, WW: false };
function expandNextPanel(panelName) {
 let lastTrue = Object.entries(panelsSaved).filter(
    ([panel, value]) => value === true && panel !== panelName
  ).pop();

  console.log(lastTrue)
}

expandNextPanel("FF");
```